# How to count duplicates in Bash Shell

Tags: bash, shell, sorting, awk

Hello guys I want to count how many duplicates there are in a column of a file and put the number next to them. I use awk and sort like this

```
awk -F '|' '{print $2}' FILE | sort | uniq -c
```

but the count (from the uniq -c) appears at the left side of the duplicates.

Is there any way to put the count on the right side instead of the left, using my code?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, if you could let us know the sample Input then we could probably do it in a single command or in better manner, let us know on same please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though I believe you shouls show us your Input_file so that we could create a single command or so for this requirement, since you have't shown Input_file so trying to solve it with your command itself.

```
awk -F '|' '{print $2}' FILE | sort | uniq -c | awk '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){printf("%s ",$i)};printf("%s%s",$1,RS)}'
```

Comment: yeah that works! The input_file has the format like this:

id|browser|name|surname|etc

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F '|' '{print $2}' FILE | sort | uniq -c| awk '{a=$1; $1=""; gsub(/^ /,"",$0);print $0,a}'
```

Comment: Logic will work but it may give initial spaces to each line, since we are nullifying the first field.

Comment: your edited one makes Internet Explorer one word InternetExplorer

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `awk` to reverse the output like below:

`awk -F '|' '{print $2}' FILE | sort | uniq -c | awk {'print $2" "$1'}`

Comment: for "7 Internet Explorer" output will be "Internet 7" not "Internet Explorer 7"

Comment: thanks for the reply but there is a problem. With your way the " 7 Internet Explorer" makes it "Internet 7" without the Explorer part

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk` to calculate the amount of duplicates, so your command can be simplified as followed,

```
awk -F '|' '{a[$2]++}END{for(i in a) print i,a[i]}' FILE | sort
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this command:

```
awk -F '|' '{c[$2]++} END{for (i in c) print i, c[i]}' FILE | sort
```

Use awk to do the counting is enough. If you do not want to sort by browser, remove the pipe and sort.

Comment: Almost the same answer with mine. :)

Comment: Yep. After I posted my answer, I found your answer has just been posted, and exactly the same. And I think these two answers are the best to the question so far.